# No slot QProcess::finished() signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qprocess, qt-signals

I am trying to run a command line program, *gphoto2* from my Qt app running on Linux, and read the results that it outputs to *Standard Output* and *Standard Error*.

The GUI in this proof of concept program is a single push button and a label that is used to display the output from *Standard Error* and *Standard Output*.

I'm having trouble connecting the `QProcess::finished` signal to the correct slot. I copied the arguments list from the `finished()` signal documentation in the header, the connect statement, and the function.

The function name is prefixed with the `MainWindow::` class identifier.

*mainwindow.h*:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
    
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QString>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QObject>
    
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}
    
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
        
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void reply2();    
        
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void on_cameraControlExit(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus);
    
    
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QProcess* cameraControl;
};
    
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`mainwindow.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>
#include <QShortcut>
#include <QDebug>
        
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    cameraControl = new QProcess(this);            
}
    
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    cameraControl->close();
    delete cameraControl;
}
    
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //connect the camera control finished signal to the slot that will read the exit code and
    //place the std output string from the process into a label on the form
    connect(cameraControl, SIGNAL(finished(int , QProcess::ExitStatus )),
            this, SLOT(MainWindow::on_cameraControlExit(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)));
    
    //Disable the ui button do we don't get double presses
    ui->pushButton->setDisabled(true);
    
    //setup the gphoto2 arguments list
    QStringList args;      
    args.append("--capture-image-and-download");
        
    //start the camera control
    cameraControl->start("gphoto2",args);
    
    //wait for the process to finish or 30 seconds whichever comes first
    cameraControl->waitForFinished(30000);
}
    
void MainWindow::on_cameraControlExit(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
{
    qDebug() << cameraControl->errorString();
    qDebug() << cameraControl->readAllStandardError();
    qDebug() << cameraControl->readAllStandardOutput();
    
    ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the following will work:

```
connect(cameraControl, SIGNAL(finished(int , QProcess::ExitStatus )), this, SLOT(on_cameraControlExit(int , QProcess::ExitStatus )));
```

Comment: Also you may want to rename your slot on_cameraControlExit and remove the on_ prefix. Why I say that is Qt may warn that it can not automatically connecting a slot if you name your slots with that prefix. on_pushButton_clicked is good because it can automatically connect that to your pushButton.

Answer (score 10):

Or with C++14 (modern compilers)

```
QObject::connect(cameraControl, qOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus >(&QProcess::finished), this, &MainWindow::on_cameraControlExit);
```

Or in the [Qt5 convention](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax):

```
QObject::connect(cameraControl, static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished), this, &MainWindow::on_cameraControlExit);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think it happens because finished signal function is overloaded with 2 signatures and the compiler has trouble to infer the type:

```
void finished(int exitCode); 
void finished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus);
```

Here is my quick-and-dirty workaround:

1) Open qprocess.h

2) Comment the "shorter" signatures:

```
//  void finished(int exitCode);
```

3) Then connect finished-signal with your lambda slot:

```
 QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::finished, [=](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
       qDebug() << "finished. Exit code: " + exitCode ;
    });
```