# Hide console window when gui program sends commands to a cli program?

Tags: c++, qt, hide, system, command-prompt

In my project, I have made a GUI program that will occasionally send commands to a cli program. I do it like this:

```
system("folder\\program.exe -d folder\\inputFile.dat folder\\outputPath");
```

Obviously without those names but you get the idea. This works fine, except when my GUI program sends these commands, a command prompt window opens and does whatever the cli program is supposed to do. It looks very bad and unclean.

Is there any way I could "hide" the cli program window but still have it silently do what it needs to do?

Thanks for your time :)

EDIT: I tried olive's technique which was to use QDesktopServices and QUrl to call the program:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("folder\\program.exe -d folder\\inputFile.dat folder\\outputPath"));
```

The console window isn't showing up, however, the program wasn't called at all. Are there any changes that need to be made to the path when using olive's technique rather than my original system() command?

Comment: You mean to say, you want to start another process from your GUI app?

Comment: Not really. I have an external .exe that I can send commands to. I just made a GUI that will occasionally run those command-line programs, but I don't want the command prompt window popping up.

Comment: Sending commands means parameter of program.exe while starting?

Comment: Yes. For example, if I wanted to decompress something I would do: system("program.exe -decompress inputFile.dat outputPath");

Answer (score 2):

I cannot determine whether you need a cross platform solution or not. On windows execution using start generally hides the command window.

```
system("start program.exe -d inputFile.dat outputPath");
```

Comment: No. In fact, it seemed to display two windows, and then it didn't seem to run properly.

Comment: @mc360pro: Ok. Then it behaves differently when executed through system. For the startup of the main app itself I know it to be effective.

Comment: Also, it did actually run, but it seems like my next line (to open the newly created file) can't work because (i'm guessing here) it never waited until the cli program was finished before moving on.

Comment: @mc360pro : I would use QProcess and catch the finished() signal. Then open the file. There could perhaps still be a premature opening if not all that is written have been flushed to disk.

Comment: I'm taking a different approach. In fact, I used QProcess::execute() and it works like system() did, but this time the command prompt window opens for a split second and is blank. Still, I don't want that, but it's closer.

Comment: After some more testing, it seems like I can only run the program when using "start" once. When I try to run it again, nothing happens.

Comment: @mc360pro : A guess: existing file is somehow blocking.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem like so:

QProcess::execute("start program.exe -d inputFile.dat outputPath");

The problem is, I can only do this once. Everytime I try to call it again, it will not work. The thing that makes this hidden is "start." Taking it out allows the console to be seen, it's just blank.

It seems like I need a way to "end" the program or whatever before running it again. (I say or whatever because I have no clue what/why adding "start" to the path does)

Comment: The program should normally end when it has completed, but then you open the file. That prevents over-writing it. Apart from that I have no clue because I am working on linux 95% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for misleading with QDesktopService::URL, later i understood that it wont accept parameter.

So implemented by improving error handling, if process not started/exited badly or waitfor the process to finish the task..I think this is useful

In QProcess, execute is blocking thread, but start is resuming the thread.

Current code is using start()  API, but more or less featurewise like execute..

> Code is copied from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534367/qt-no-such-slot-for-the-qprocessfinished-signal) and modified little for the current requirements.

**> Mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>
#include <QShortcut>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    cameraControl = new QProcess(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    cameraControl->close();
    delete cameraControl;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    // connect the camera control finished signal to the slot that will read the exit code and
    // place the std output string from the process into a label on the form
    connect(cameraControl, SIGNAL(finished(int , QProcess::ExitStatus )),
            this, SLOT(on_cameraControlExit(int , QProcess::ExitStatus )));

    // Disable the ui button do we don't get double presses
    ui->pushButton->setDisabled(true);

    // setup the gphoto2 arguments list
    QStringList args;
    args.append("d:\\text.txt");

    // start the camera control
    cameraControl->start("notepad",args);

//    // wait for the process to finish or 30 seconds whichever comes first
    cameraControl->waitForFinished(30000);

}



void MainWindow::on_cameraControlExit(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
{
    qDebug() << cameraControl->errorString();
    qDebug() << cameraControl->readAllStandardError();
    qDebug() << cameraControl->readAllStandardOutput();
    ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);

}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QString>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QObject>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void reply2();


private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void on_cameraControlExit(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus);


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QProcess* cameraControl;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Actually, no it didn't. It didn't do anything. Is there a reason you included c:\\??? What I mean is, it seems like the program was never run.

EDIT: I see you added ~    Still nothing.

Comment: @mc360pro Removed hard coded path, you can give your path/or directly according to your system environments

Comment: I'm using the same path that would be in my system() command. I messed around with it too. It's like it's not even doing anything. hmmm :/

Comment: Would there be any changes I would need to make to the path when using this instead of my original system() command? Because the program runs when I call it with system().

Comment: This does not work properly. The program will run, but the window still displays.

Answer (score 0):

`QDesktopServices::openUrl()` is usually used if you wish to open a document (eg PDF document, web page) in a viewing or editing program and you're not sure which programs have been installed. This function lets the operating system choose for you from the list of default programs with respect to the file types.

Although you can also use the function to open executable files (eg console programs), an alternative to that would be using `QProcess`. If you don't need to communicate with the console program or wait for it to complete, you can just launch it in a fire-and-forget fashion using one of the two `QProcess::startDetached()` static functions

[QProcess::startDetached](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html#startDetached-2)

Answer (score -3):

in your Qt program,there is a .pro file.You can add this line into the file:
config+=console

Comment: @Robin I would like to say, Above answer doesn't add any value to the problem.